# set sequence animated-vector

Tags: android, vector, android-animation

I'm developing a first run which shows an animation that shows the user he can receive pushes.
The animation shows a push notification translating over the y-axis while on the same time doing an alpha transition.

[image]

This works perfectly.

However after this animation stops I want to draw a series of sequential animations. This however seems not possible to do because all the animations start at the same time.

Is it possible to group a set of animations to start at the same time and others as sequential?
I know I could set an offset on each of these sequential animations, but I wonder if there is a cleaner solution.

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vector_drawable">

    <!-- translate notification to the top -->
    <target
        android:name="notification"
        android:animation="@animator/notification_translate_y" />

    <!-- set notification visible while translating -->
    <target
        android:name="notification_part1"
        android:animation="@animator/notification_alpha" />
    <target
        android:name="notification_part2"
        android:animation="@animator/notification_alpha" />
    <target
        android:name="notification_part3"
        android:animation="@animator/notification_alpha" />
    <target
        android:name="notification_part4"
        android:animation="@animator/notification_alpha" />
    <target
        android:name="notification_part5"
        android:animation="@animator/notification_alpha" />
    <target
        android:name="logo_1"
        android:animation="@animator/notification_alpha" />

    <target
        android:name="logo_2"
        android:animation="@animator/notification_alpha" />

    <!-- after translation and alpha do a set of sequential animations -->
    <!-- NOT WORKING STARTS WITH TRANSLATION AND ALPHA ANIMATION -->
   <target
        android:name="logo_2"
        android:animation="@animator/some_other_animation" />
   <target
        android:name="someOtherTarget"
        android:animation="@animator/some_other_animation" />
</animated-vector>
```

Comment: Are you doing the alpha transition on the whole vector drawable, or just certain parts?

Comment: I do it on the notification part. However I have to define a <target> for each path.

Comment: just asking as it is possible to do the whole vector drawable alpha using one <target> if that's what you're aiming for

Comment: how? could you show me? Because I could wrap it in a <group> but I don't have a property alpha on a <group>-tag

Comment: yes of course. I'll post it as an answer in a few minutes so I can format it better and comment on the sequential animation bit too

Answer (score 2):

Using startDelay to achieve the sequential look is probably the way to go here.

Note, if you didn't need to animate "someOtherTarget" in your AnimatedVectorDrawable definition, you could combine the animations for logo_2 (i.e. notification_alpha and some_other_animation) into a sequential AnimatorSet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
    <objectAnimator
        ...
        android:propertyName="alpha" />
    <objectAnimator
        ...
        android:propertyName="some_other_attribute" />
</set>
```

AnimatedVectorDrawable doesn't yet support repeating/looping. You could work around that by registering an Animation callback through `registerAnimationCallback(Animatable2.AnimationCallback callback)`, and restart the animations once they end.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've already mentioned it in the question, I think startOffset is the right thing to do here.
The way to do that reasonably cleanly is to set the duration in a file in res/values and refer to that in your objectAnimators, so in res/values you would have an xml resource like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<integer name="first_part_of_anim_duration">4000</integer>
...
...
</resources>
```

Then in your objectAnimators that are first have:

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="@integer/first_part_of_anim_duration"
    ...
    />
```

And the next ones in line would show

```
<objectAnimator
    android:startOffset="@integer/first_part_of_anim_duration"
    android:duration="...something else..."
    ...
    />
```

So if you change timing of the first part you only need to change one number and everything will still follow directly on.

In the comments we discussed combining all the alpha transitions into one. Here's how you do it.
As you rightly said you can't set alpha on a `<group>` in a vector drawable, but you *can* set it on the *whole vector drawable*.
So the opening of your vector drawable tag look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:height="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:name="name of whole vector drawable">
....
</vector>
```

Then your `<target>` can be simply:

```
<target
    android:name="name of whole vector drawable"
    android:animation="@animator/notification_alpha" />
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not working. Even thought my offsets are set correctly. If you want my code is on github https://github.com/timrijckaert/vector-compat-test/tree/master

Comment: A few things I noticed, from grabbing a copy of this earlier. The objectAnimators are all set to repeat continuously. What this means is that each individual one will repeat, not that the whole animation repeats. So the translate_y animation completes, at this point the animators with the startOffset will begin, but the translate_y animator will also start again. I'd start by remove the repeat settings from all the animators. It also looks like all the `_visible` and `_invisible` animators are reversed, so the one's you want to change the alpha from 0 to 1, are actually changing it from 1 to 0

Comment: I know what you are saying, however I'm stuck. I don't get the logic behind it. Could you be so kind to maybe show me in my example? Plus I want the animation to repeat itself over and over again. Pull request?

Comment: I updated my repo to match what you are saying. However I do want the animation to repeat itself. Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure there's a good way to make it loop, it's one of the things I think is lacking in AnimatedVectorDrawables and that will hopefully be addressed when it's added to the support library.